# How to add a button to an item in a to do list in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using `shinydashboardplus`.

I'd like to use the to do list but the example in the gallery is limited to just showing a list without any functionality.

To track a todo list for a user I am reading and writing to a csv for the moment.

I can read the csv to dynamically populate the list. Now I'd like to be able to strike through an item to indicate it is completed using the `checked` parameter.

The checked items should be removed from the csv.

Ill work on the adding items another day I think....

Here is my example (not reading from csv but from iris for this example).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
    useShinydashboardPlus(),
    

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            box(
                "Sortable todo list demo",
                status = "warning",
                todoList(
                    apply(mtcars,1, function(x)
                        todoListItem(
                            label = x[1],
                            x[2]
                        )
                    )

            )        
            )
    )
)
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: No longer interested in this?

Comment: Just about to try it out. Ill get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `renderUI` and a reactive data.frame:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)

css <- "
.inlinecheckbox .shiny-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(css),
  titlePanel("Dynamic to do list"),
  useShinydashboardPlus(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      box(
        "Sortable todo list demo",
        status = "warning",
        uiOutput("myToDoList")     
      )
    )
  )
)

checkboxIDs <- paste0("checkbox", seq_len(nrow(mtcars)))
mtcars$checked <- FALSE

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  reactiveMtcars <- reactiveVal(mtcars)
  
  observe({
    for (i in seq_along(checkboxIDs)) {
      if(!is.null(input[[checkboxIDs[1]]])){
        mtcars$checked[i] <- input[[checkboxIDs[i]]]  
      }
    }
    
    reactiveMtcars(mtcars)
  })
  
  output$myToDoList <- renderUI({
    req(reactiveMtcars())
    todoListItems <- list() 
    for(i in seq_len(nrow(reactiveMtcars()))){
      todoListItems[[i]] <- todoListItem(
        label = div(rownames(reactiveMtcars())[i], style = ""), 
        span(class = "inlinecheckbox", checkboxInput(inputId = paste0("checkbox", i), label = NULL, value = reactiveMtcars()$checked[i])),
        checked = reactiveMtcars()$checked[i],
      )
    }
    
    todoList(todoListItems)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Result]